# Updating multiple tables with LINQ and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

Just a quick one really, I'm just looking for a bit of clarification.

I'm looking to update multiple tables from one "Create" action, before I try it, I was just wondering if it's possible to simply just do the following:

```
db.hdCalls.InsertOnSubmit(a)
db.hdCustomers.InsertOnSubmit(b)
db.hdAssign.InsertOnSubmit(c)
db.SubmitChanges()
```

Or is it slightly more complicated than that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, SubmitChanges will then call 3 inserts.

Answer (score 1):

A small question even if this post is old.

What if one of the inserts fails, will all the other inserts rollback?
Because if one fail, I sure does not want any of the other inserts to commit.

How is this handled?

Comment: It's my understanding that if any of those fail under db.SubmitChanges() the whole insert fails, not just one.